# System-size dependent phase transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

I noticed that some physical phenomena require a system of size above some critical value to be observed. Two examples I know are:

- For a single-atom gold wire, there is a critical number of atoms to see conductance [private com., reference?]
- It was found that 60 $^4$He atoms are needed to permit molecular superfluidity to occur [http://science.sciencemag.org/content/279/5359/2083.long]

Do you know more examples?

Comment: Theoretically, as the system size $N \to \infty$, some zeros of partition function $Z$ approaches to real axis, and hence phase transition is possible. So I guess the threshold or critical value depends on how fast those zeros approaches to real axis.

Comment: I am not sure the question is really answerable: for small systems, it becomes very delicate to provide clear-cut definitions of phases and, a fortiori, of phase transitions...

Comment: @YvanVelenik thank you for your comment. Please note that I'm not asking for general statements/theorems... I asked for examples similar to the one I propose, if possible.